# How to .map() through an array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to map through some data that looks like this:

```
[
{
  "id": "cambridgeshire",
  "name": "Cambridgeshire"
},
{
  "id": "bedfordshire",
  "name": "Bedfordshire"
}
]
```

And display it as a list.

I'm getting the error of allAreas is undefined. I have a feeling its because of the JSON Object which I'm unfamiliar with.

On checking the state of allAreas it shows undefined.

Heres the code Ive tried

```
const Directory = () => {
  const [allAreas, setAllAreas] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllAreasData().then((data) => setAllAreas(data));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className='directory'>
      <ul>
        {allAreas.map((area) => (
          <li key={area.id}>{area.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

To clarify this is an array of objects

Comment: The initial value of `allAreas` is an empty object `useState({})`. Use `useState([])`

Comment: Ok I did that and now have the error allAreas is undefined. And Ive just checked the state of allAreas and it reads undefined.

Comment: can you please show a console.log of data returned from fetchAllAreasData?

Comment: [
  {
    "id": "avon-and-somerset",
    "name": "Avon and Somerset"
  },
  {
    "id": "bedfordshire",
    "name": "Bedfordshire"
  },
  {
    "id": "cambridgeshire",
    "name": "Cambridgeshire"
  },
  {
    "id": "cheshire",
    "name": "Cheshire Constabulary"
  },
  {
    "id": "city-of-london",
    "name": "City of London"
  }
]

Comment: looks like the function `fetchAllAreasData` maybe returning `undefined`, check the `data` you're receiving is expected.

Comment: here `{allAreas.map((area) =>()}` change this to `{allAreas.length > 0 && allAreas.map((area) =>()}. In initial `allAreas` is an empty array, so `array.map()` will throw an error.

Comment: Hi @akhil, I'd like to clear this. No, an empty array wouldn't throw you an error when you try to map it. The problem here is the suppose to be an array of allAreas had turned into undefined. Because "undefined" have no map function. It threw an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the allArea exists before mapping.

```js
const Directory = () => {
  const [allAreas, setAllAreas] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllAreasData().then((data) => setAllAreas(data));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className='directory'>
      <ul>
        {allAreas && allAreas.map((area) => (
          <li key={area.id}>{area.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If your problem didn't fix, use the useReducer instead because of some react problems in useState with arrays in sometimes.something like this:

```js
function reducer(state = [], action) {
 return action;
}

const Directory = () => {
  const [allAreas, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllAreasData().then((data) => dispatch(data));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className='directory'>
      <ul>
        {allAreas.length > 0 && allAreas.map((area) => (
          <li key={area.id}>{area.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [allAreas, setAllAreas] = useState([]); // your defaulted state must be [] instead of {}
```

Comment: Ok I did that and now have the error allAreas is undefined.

Comment: It is probably the "data" response of your `fetchAllAreasData`. Have you tried checking that and confirm that it is an array object?

Comment: was that inside the "then" of fetchAllAreasData? Try this to check if you got a response`fetchAllAreasData.then((data) => console.log(data))`?

Answer (score 0):

Just change first line of the function to :

```
const [allAreas, setAllAreas] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be issue because your map function gets called before promise resolved and you get data.

To avoid this please check the length of `'allAreas'` before iterating over it.

Also the intitial values assigned to `'allAreas'` object instead of array.
Change initial assignment to an array.

```
const Directory = () => {
  const [allAreas, setAllAreas] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllAreasData().then((data) => setAllAreas(data));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className='directory'>
      <ul>
        {allAreas.lenght && allAreas.map((area) => (
          <li key={area.id}>{area.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

try,

```
 <ul>
     {allAreas && allAreas.map((area) => (
         <li key={area.id}>{area.name}</li>
     ))}
 </ul>
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also include what the code does and how it helps.